# Flash over RTSP?

Tags: quicktime, rtsp

Got two servers that serve up a swf file thay plays an audio file users must type in (a medical word).

One server (and my local build) serve up the flash just fine. But one tries to launch it as a RTSP thing. I have no experience in this area (RTSP) so is it possible to somehow tell the browser to serve up a flash object as RTSP?

Does this even make sense?

Thanks SO! :)

Answer (score 2):

RTSP is just a protocol:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol

like RTMP (a proprietary protocol for serving flash) but open. It seems to me that your client (a flash client or...?) has RTSP:// built into the call. You can get around this most likely by checking the parameters of your flash client. With Flowplayer you can specifically tell it to use HTTP, RTMP, or RTSP - but it defaults to HTTP.

So before I go any further - how is the SWF being consumed on the client?

Comment: Through a object type="x-shockwave-flash" for both

Comment: If the SWF is an audio player it's probably set to use RTSP. I'm going to guess there's a params switch that you can tell it to use HTTP. Is it home-grown or 3rd party? Have you looked at the docs?